# Find names of columns which contain missing values

Tags: r, na

I want to find all the names of columns with `NA` or missing data and store these column names in a vector.

```
# create matrix
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA,7,8,9,10,NA,12,13,14,NA,16,17,18,19,20)
cnames <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee")
mymatrix <- matrix(a, nrow = 4, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(mymatrix) <- cnames
mymatrix
#      aa bb cc dd ee
# [1,]  1  2  3  4  5
# [2,] NA  7  8  9 10
# [3,] NA 12 13 14 NA
# [4,] 16 17 18 19 20
```

The desired result: columns `"aa"` and `"ee"`.

My attempt:

```
bad <- character()
for (j in 1:4){     
  tmp <- which(colnames(mymatrix[j, ]) %in% c("", "NA"))
  bad <- tmp
}
```

However, I keep getting `integer(0)` as my output. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Like this?

```
colnames(mymatrix)[colSums(is.na(mymatrix)) > 0]
# [1] "aa" "ee"
```

Or as suggested by @thelatemail:

```
names(which(colSums(is.na(mymatrix)) > 0))
# [1] "aa" "ee"
```

Answer (score 21):

R 3.1 introduced an `anyNA` function, which is more convenient and faster:

```
colnames(mymatrix)[ apply(mymatrix, 2, anyNA) ]
```

Old answer:

If it's a very long matrix, `apply` + `any` can short circuit and run a bit faster.

```
apply(is.na(mymatrix), 2, any)
#   aa    bb    cc    dd    ee 
# TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE 
colnames(mymatrix)[apply(is.na(mymatrix), 2, any)]
# [1] "aa" "ee"
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have a data frame with non-numeric columns, this solution is more general (building on previous answers):

R 3.1 +

`names(which(sapply(mymatrix, anyNA)))`

or

`names(which(sapply(mymatrix, function(x) any(is.na(x)))))`