# Data Wrangle in R - How do I list out columns that have over a certain number of a specific value from a tibble

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

I am trying to work with a data set that uses the value -4 instead of NA as the NA value. So I have found the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20364450/find-names-of-columns-which-contain-missing-values/20364570), which gets me close but I am not sure how to generalize this?

```
colnames(data)[colSums(is.na(data)) > 1000]
```

I tried using funcion(x)which(x <0) in place of is.na(data) but that did not go very well.

How can I achieve this aim?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `dplyr::na_if()` what you need? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html

Comment: Why don't you first replace these user-defined NAs with proper NAs, as in `data%>%mutate(across(everything(), ~na_if(., -4)))` first, and only then select your data?

Answer (score 2):

One option using `dplyr` would be to count all of the `-4` values, then `select` only the columns with a count of over 1000.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  summarize_all(~sum(. == -4)) %>% 
  select_if(~. > 1000) %>% 
  colnames()
```

To be even more explicit, you could convert the `-4` values to `NA` first.

```
data %>% 
  na_if(-4) %>%
  summarize_all(~sum(is.na(.))) %>% 
  select_if(~. > 1000) %>% 
  colnames()
```

---

Or a `base` solution, slightly modifying your original code to count `-4` values rather than `NA` values.

```
colnames(data)[colSums(data == -4) > 1000]
```